# Redis doesn't return WRONGTYPE as an error in a transaction

Tags: go, redis

Appologies if this was already asked. First, let me show how to reproduce my problem:

1. Run Redis in a docker container
2. Connect to Redis and execute the following command:

```
> SET test 10
```

3. In Go, run this code:

```golang
func main() {
    redisClient := getConnection() // Abstracting get connection for simplicity

    r, err := redisClient.Do("HSET", "test", "f1", "v1", "f2", "v2")
    fmt.Printf("%+v e: %+v\n")
}
```

Fair enough, in this step the following error is shown (this means `err != nil`):

```
WRONGTYPE Operation against a key holding the wrong kind of value e: WRONGTYPE Operation against a key holding the wrong kind of value
```

4. In comparison, execute the following code:

```golang
func main() {
    redisClient := getConnection()

    redisClient.Send("MULTI")

    redisClient.Send("HSET", "test", "f1", "v1", "f2", "v2")

    r, err := redisClient.Do("EXEC")
    fmt.Printf("%+v e: %+v\n")
}
```

The line being printed is:

```
WRONGTYPE Operation against a key holding the wrong kind of value e: <nil>
```

This seems inconsistent to me as I would expect `MULTI` to return the `WRONGTYPE` in the error variable as well.

Is this an intended behavior or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two results for each command in a Redis transaction.  One is the result for adding the command to the transaction and the other is the result for executing the command in the transaction.

The `Do` method returns the result for adding the command to the transaction.

The Redis [EXEC](https://redis.io/commands/exec) command returns an array where each element is the result of executing the command in the transaction.  Examine each element to check individual command errors:

```
values, err := redis.Values(redisClient.Do("EXEC"))
if err != nil {
    // Handle error
}
if err, ok := values[0].(redis.Error); ok {
    // Handle error for command 0.
    // Adjust the index to match the actual index of 
    // of the HMSET command in the transaction.
}
```

A helper function for testing transaction command errors may be useful:

```
func execValues(reply interface{}, err error) ([]interface{}, error) {
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    values, ok := reply.([]interface{})
    if !ok {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("unexpected type for EXEC reply, got type %T", reply)
    }
    for _, v := range values {
        if err, ok := v.(redis.Error); ok {
            return values, err
        }
    }
    return values, nil
}
```

Use it like this:

```
values, err := execValues(redisClient.Do("EXEC"))
if err != nil {
    // Handle error.
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I will give it a try later today. However, what confuses me is that the documenation states "if any of the received replies is an error, then Do returns the error" (https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/gomodule/redigo/redis#hdr-Pipelining). This makes me think that if any command fails, I should get an error when executing `Do("EXEC")`.

Comment: @Rick Do returns the error for adding the command to the transaction.  Examine the EXEC result to get the error for executing the command in the transaction.